# how to change language of language selection dialog in inno-setup?

Tags: inno-setup

My customer wants installer's language selection dialog to be in english, but there's no English in selectable languages list now. And i do not want to add English because i have a set of my own strings in installer which will also require eng. localization. I don't need English anywhere except language selection dialog. Is there a way to either set that dialog message language manually or add english as default language and remove it from combo-box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text strings on that dialog come from the language file so if you want that to display in english, you must have the english language strings included.

You may be able to hack around this by adding custom message text for each language you support replacing with the english version

```
[Messages]
russian.SelectLanguageTitle=Select Setup Language
russian.SelectLanguageLabel=Select the language to use during the installation:
polish.SelectLanguageTitle=Select Setup Language
polish.SelectLanguageLabel=Select the language to use during the installation:
chinese.SelectLanguageTitle=Select Setup Language
chinese.SelectLanguageLabel=Select the language to use during the installation:
```

Comment: Thanks! It's true, there is message overrinding section in script file.